# How to parse a facebook graph api response

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook graph api request which brings back this response

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 111
                                [from] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 111
                                        [name] => fo bar
                                    )

                                [name] => etc

                            )
```

I've tried to do `$reponse->{'backingData:protected'}` but it doesn't work.

Also the next set of results is a link to the graph api but the results from this is pure json.

```
    [paging] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cursors] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [after] => MTI3NzMzMTQwMzYy
                    [before] => MTAxNTQzNjI5NTY1NDAzNjM=
                )

            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/111/albums?access_token=xxxxv&limit=25&after=yyy
        )
```

My code

```
    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me/albums'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_profile); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: `$response->data[0]->id` I think

Comment: can you post php code here?

Comment: No I get 'Cannot use object of type Facebook\GraphObject as array'

Comment: try this `$data = $response->getData()` then `print_r($data);`

Comment: Added code example and @bhushya no that doesn't work either

Comment: I mean you tried `$user_profile->getData()` r8? or `print_r($user_profile->getProperty('data'));`

Comment: `print_r($user_profile->getProperty('data'))` produce the same output except for `[data] => Array`, but when I do `$user_profile->getProperty('data')[0]` I get errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57792/discussion-between-bhushya-and-user9418).

Comment: @user9418 can you explain what exact error u got?

Answer (score 17):

Here is the way:

```
        $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me/albums'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
        $album =  $user_profile->getProperty('data');

        $album_data = $album->asArray();//this will do all job for you..
        foreach($album_data as $row){
            var_dump($row);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't provide any output in the foreach, I've added the array output in your post above. But when you try and iterate over it nothing is generated.

Comment: what error u got ehrn you printed `$user_profile->getProperty('data')[0]`

Comment: `[2014-07-22 22:33:41] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Cannot use object of type Facebook\GraphObject as array' in /var/www/app/controllers/FacebookController.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []`

The output without the [0] is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e345f124f7efcd076b5

Comment: @user9418 Can you try this `print_r($album_data->asArray())`?? im sure this will work :)

Comment: @bhushya +1 I agree, answer should be accepted. It has somewhat helped with my [Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267526/how-to-read-large-facebook-array-remastered-recycled-05-02-2015) as it is showing data but the outcome is a mess and I don't know how to get value X

Answer (score 6):

For the New version Graph API v2.5 of Facebook Read read data as below :

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'KEY HERE',
        'app_secret' => 'SECRET HERE',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
 $asscee_t ="ACCESS TOKEN HERE";
    $response = $fb->get('/me/friends', $asscee_t);
        $get_data = $response->getDecodedBody(); // for Array resonse
        //$get_data = $response->getDecodedBody(); // For Json format result only
        echo $get_data['summary']['total_count']; die; // Get total number of Friends
```

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0

**getProperty**

getProperty`(string $name, string $type = 'Facebook\GraphObject')`
Gets the value of a named key for this graph object. If the value is a scalar (string, number, etc.) it will be returned. If it's an associative array, it will be returned as a GraphObject cast to the appropriate subclass type if provided.

```
 $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me/albums'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

$id = $user_profile->getProperty('id');
```

full list of field in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album

Comment: The getProperty function does not capture all use cases. For example, the /me/permission returns an extremely ugly data (no surprise there) that cannot be parsed with getProperty or at least I couldn't find a solution on the internet that used it. However, Bhushya's answer is the way to go. Facebook is so stupid that it returned me a graphobject containing an array containing a graphobject for a single data entry. And hardcoding anything like data[0] is completely unacceptable to me as a programmer. Plus, facebook changes things a lot and hides it in their changelog hidden in the dev site. dtf