# How to traverse this object PHP

Tags: php

I just print facebook api resonse

```
print_r($response)
```

output is

```
Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object
(
[request:protected] => Facebook\FacebookRequest Object
    (
        [app:protected] => Facebook\FacebookApp Object
            (
                [id:protected] => secret
                [secret:protected] => secret
            )

        [accessToken:protected] => secret
        [method:protected] => GET
        [endpoint:protected] => /search?q=co&type=page
        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            )

        [params:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [files:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [eTag:protected] => 
        [graphVersion:protected] => v2.5
    )

[metaData:protected] => Array
    (
        [paging] => Array
            (
                [cursors] => Array
                    (
                        [before] => MAZDZD
                        [after] => MjQZD
                    )

                [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?access_token=EAAafvw8PPA4BACHY8V6GDpbzMbtRlZC7dZCRnOGtO26Yc4g4yWWvqZCsMBPOWO3b72n2JPjXP8KD91ZCMXMAcARGUsk5cNShhy5LxOmj0Gz4ZA2ESzPZAd4VzBCpdZATCZBvZCOkAIxBd1gXBzkMY0DheyjruSlMHEPbbuVuTY350wgZDZD&q=co&type=page&limit=25&after=MjQZD
            )

    )

[parentEdgeEndpoint:protected] => 
[subclassName:protected] => 
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
            (
                [items:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => SC Corinthians Paulista
                        [id] => 132769576762243
                    )

            )

        [1] => Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphNode Object
            (
                [items:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Miranda Cosgrove
                        [id] => 9934379006
                    )
```

I want to access `[items:protected]` array .But i can't find how to get their

I tried

$items_array = $response->items:protected;

But this is not working , please help me. I want to get that array and iterate over it

Comment: You cannot access protected data types

Comment: really , no way ? @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: I suppose you can iterate over items with simple `foreach`, as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0

Comment: @u_mulder link is looking helpful

Comment: You can access private/protected properties, via either [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) or serialization or cloning etc etc. There are ways. With that said, you shouldn't. They're protected/private for a reason. Instead search for getters in the class.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897838/how-to-parse-a-facebook-graph-api-response  ,  bhushya solution, works for me, thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse this object using a couple of different techniques:

(Recommended Technique:) You can use the GraphNode object's methods to output the items all at once by looping through the GraphEdge object to get the GraphNode and calling 'asJson()' or 'asArray()' on it:

```
foreach($response as $node){
    //Print as json
    print($node->asJson());

    //Print as array
    print_r($node->asArray());
}
```

There are other methods for accessing the GraphNode object properties such as 'getField' and 'getFieldNames' if you want to only get a specific item of data and don't want to return the whole thing (you can read about them here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0)

(Also works:) Or you can use nested foreach loops (as per docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0).

Something along the lines of:

```
foreach ($response as $node) {
    //each item returned by response
    foreach ($node as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
        //each item within the node
        print $itemKey.' is '.$itemValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is protected, it means you can't access from the outside. I d suggest you to have a look in the class Facebook\FacebookRequest if there is a public method that is providing you items, else you can't access to this.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook php api suggests simple [`foreach`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphEdge/5.0.0) to get nodes:

```
foreach ($response as $graphNode) {
    print_r($graphNode);
}
```

How to work with `GraphNode` object described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code source of this object in the facebook github repo : [Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphEdge](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.4/src/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphEdge.php)

GraphEdge extends [Collection](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.4/src/Facebook/GraphNodes/Collection.php) which implements ArrayAccess and IteratorAggregate

Iterator is made on $items properties...

```
/**
 * Get an iterator for the items.
 *
 * @return ArrayIterator
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    return new ArrayIterator($this->items);
}
```

Then yes, using a simple `foreach` should work